# iOS Swift: Trying to use write image buffer to construct video, finishWritingWithCompletionHandler not called. Output video contains zero bytes

Tags: ios, video, swift, avfoundation

I'm trying to just write only two frames from a static image to construct a video. I've been mugging around the time parameters a bit. Seems the last step finishWritingWithCompletionHandler never been called (finished writing... never get outputted). There is only a zero byte .mp4 video created. And there is no errors occurred. Can't figure out why. Here's the code that I use:

```
func createBackgroundVideo(CompletionHandler: (path: String)->Void) {

    var maybeError: NSError?
    let fileMgr = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    let docDirectory = NSHomeDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent("Documents")
    let videoOutputPath = docDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent(BgVideoName)

    if (!fileMgr.removeItemAtPath(videoOutputPath, error: &maybeError)) {
        NSLog("Umable to delete file: %@", maybeError!.localizedDescription)
    }

    println(videoOutputPath)

    let videoWriter = AVAssetWriter(
        URL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: videoOutputPath),
        fileType: AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie,
        error: &maybeError
    )

    var videoSettings = [
        AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecH264,
        AVVideoWidthKey: NSNumber(float: Float(videoWidth)),
        AVVideoHeightKey: NSNumber(float: Float(videoHeight))
    ]

    var avAssetInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, outputSettings: videoSettings)
    avAssetInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = true

    var adaptor = AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor(assetWriterInput: avAssetInput, sourcePixelBufferAttributes: nil)

    videoWriter.addInput(avAssetInput)
    videoWriter.startWriting()
    videoWriter.startSessionAtSourceTime(kCMTimeZero)

    var frameCount: Int64 = 0;
    var buffer: CVPixelBufferRef

    //buffer = PixelBuffer.pixelBufferFromCGImage2(self.bgImage.CGImage, andSize: CGSizeMake(videoWidth, videoHeight)).takeUnretainedValue()

    for i in 1...2 {
        buffer = PixelBuffer.pixelBufferFromCGImage2(self.bgImage.CGImage, andSize: CGSizeMake(videoWidth, videoHeight)).takeUnretainedValue()
        var appendOk = false
        var retries: Int = 0

        while (!appendOk && retries < 30) {
            if (adaptor.assetWriterInput.readyForMoreMediaData) {
                let frameTime = CMTimeMake(frameCount, 1);
                appendOk = adaptor.appendPixelBuffer(buffer, withPresentationTime: frameTime)
                if (!appendOk) {
                    println("some erorr occurred", videoWriter.error)
                } else {
                    println("pixel written")
                }
            } else {
                println("adaptor is not ready....")
                NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(0.1)
            }
            retries++
        }

        if (!appendOk) {
            println("Error appending image....")
        }

        frameCount++
    }

    avAssetInput.markAsFinished()
    videoWriter.finishWritingWithCompletionHandler({() -> Void in
        println("finished writing...")
        CompletionHandler(path: videoOutputPath)
    })
}
```

I'm calling a pixel buffer from CGImage method written in Obj-c, (I've added headers and bridging headers, it seems working fine):

```
+ (CVPixelBufferRef) pixelBufferFromCGImage2: (CGImageRef) image andSize:(CGSize) size {

    NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey,
                             [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey,
                             nil];
    CVPixelBufferRef pxbuffer = NULL;

    CVReturn status = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                          size.width,
                                          size.height,
                                          kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB,
                                          (__bridge CFDictionaryRef) options,
                                          &pxbuffer);
    if (status != kCVReturnSuccess){
        NSLog(@"Failed to create pixel buffer");
    }

    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pxbuffer, 0);
    void *pxdata = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pxbuffer);

    CGColorSpaceRef rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pxdata, size.width,
                                                 size.height, 8, 4*size.width, rgbColorSpace,
                                                 kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);

    float offsetY = size.height / 2 - CGImageGetHeight(image) / 2;
    float offsetX = size.width / 2 - CGImageGetWidth(image) / 2;

    CGContextConcatCTM(context, CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0));
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(offsetX, offsetY, CGImageGetWidth(image),
                                           CGImageGetHeight(image)), image);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(rgbColorSpace);
    CGContextRelease(context);

    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pxbuffer, 0);

    return pxbuffer;
}
```

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your *videoSettings* dictionary is not complete. Try setting up some more atom information like this:

```
var videoCleanApertureSettings = [AVVideoCleanApertureWidthKey:Int(self.width),
                                 AVVideoCleanApertureHeightKey:Int(self.height),
                       AVVideoCleanApertureHorizontalOffsetKey:0,
                         AVVideoCleanApertureVerticalOffsetKey:0]

var videoAspectRatioSettings = [AVVideoPixelAspectRatioHorizontalSpacingKey:1,
                                  AVVideoPixelAspectRatioVerticalSpacingKey:1]

var codecSettings = [AVVideoCleanApertureKey:videoCleanApertureSettings,
                  AVVideoPixelAspectRatioKey:videoAspectRatioSettings]

var videoSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey:AVVideoCodecH264,
     AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey:codecSettings,
                     AVVideoWidthKey:Int(self.width),
                    AVVideoHeightKey:Int(self.height)]
```

You start the video at timestamp zero. That's okay:

```
[self.videoWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:kCMTimeZero];
```

Maybe your timestamps of your video images are not distant enough to see something. If you need some seconds for displaying the images you can do something like this:

```
int64_t newFrameNumber = (uint64_t)(presentationTimeInSeconds * 60.);
CMTime frameTime = CMTimeMake(newFrameNumber, 60);
```

Using 60 as timescale gives you the opportunity using seconds as unit with a good resolution.

For producing a slideshow in "realtime", you can use *NSDate* to encode the timestamp:

```
int64_t newFrameNumber = (uint64_t)(fabs([self.videoStartDate timeIntervalSinceNow]) * 60.);
```

where *self.videoStartDate* is an `[NSDate date]` value which you set immediately after starting the video.

The *CMTime* tells the decoder *when* to display the image, not for how long to display it. You start with a *frameCount* value of *0* which tells the decoder to immediately presenting the first image. Maybe you try starting with *1* to see if the video will display the first image a little bit later.

if you used `startSessionAtSourceTime` then you must end the video with `endSessionAtSourceTime` before you call `finishWritingWithCompletionHandler`, else the closure may not be called. Pass the last timestamp to *endSessionAtSourceTime*.

You could try the deprecated method from apple to see if this is maybe a bug.
After marking as finished call

```
videoWriter.finishWriting()
```

instead of `finishWritingWithCompletionHandler` and wait a little bit for the file to be closed by the diskwriter. (i.e. by using a dispatch queue)

```
int64_t delayInSeconds = 1;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

     // call your completion handler after the file has been written
})
```

Here is the swift version:

```
let delayInSeconds:Double = 0.5
let popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delayInSeconds * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

   println("finished writing...")
   CompletionHandler(path: videoOutputPath)
})
```

Maybe your *videowriter* instance doesn't exist anymore after leaving your class. (The block is called asynchronously, but you declared *videowriter* locally in your function. ARC is maybe releasing the object before the completion handler can be called.) Declare the writers globally to fix this issue.

Hint:

Keep your CGColorSpace in memory (i.e. creating a class var or a static var here), because `CGColorSpaceRef rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();` takes a long time to initialize. Doing this only once before you encode the video will increase your apps execution speed dramatically!